# Undefined reference to Sub Class

Tags: c++, class, debugging, inheritance

I have a SubClass : PointTwoD which inherits from the BaseClass : locationdata . I am getting this error : undefined reference to PointTwoD in my main function , can someone explain to me why ??

Base class locationdata.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class locationdata
{
  public:
  locationdata(); //default constructor
  locationdata(string,int,int,float,float); //constructor

 //setter
 void set_sunType(string);
 void set_noOfEarthLikePlanets(int);
 void set_noOfEarthLikeMoons(int);
 void set_aveParticulateDensity(float);
 void set_avePlasmaDensity(float);

 //getter 
 string get_sunType();
 int get_noOfEarthLikePlanets();
 int get_noOfEarthLikeMoons();
 float get_aveParticulateDensity();
 float get_avePlasmaDensity();


 float computeCivIndex();
 friend class PointTwoD;

      private:

  string sunType;
  int noOfEarthLikePlanets;
  int noOfEarthLikeMoons;
  float aveParticulateDensity;
  float avePlasmaDensity;

 };
```

Base class locationdata.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "locationdata.h"
using namespace std;

locationdata::locationdata()
{
  this->sunType = "";
  this->noOfEarthLikePlanets=0;
  this->noOfEarthLikeMoons=0;
  this->aveParticulateDensity=0;
  this->avePlasmaDensity=0;

}

locationdata::locationdata(string sunType , int noOfEarthLikePlanets , 
                       int noOfEarthLikeMoons , float aveParticulateDensity ,
                       float avePlasmaDensity)

{
    this->sunType = sunType;
this->noOfEarthLikePlanets = noOfEarthLikePlanets;
this->noOfEarthLikeMoons = noOfEarthLikeMoons;
this->aveParticulateDensity = aveParticulateDensity;
this->avePlasmaDensity = avePlasmaDensity;

}

void locationdata::set_sunType(string sunType)
{
  this->sunType = sunType;

 }

void locationdata::set_noOfEarthLikePlanets(int noOfEarthLikePlanets)
{ 

this->noOfEarthLikePlanets = noOfEarthLikePlanets;
}

void locationdata::set_noOfEarthLikeMoons(int noOfEarthLikeMoons)
{
this->noOfEarthLikeMoons = noOfEarthLikeMoons;
}

void locationdata:: set_aveParticulateDensity(float aveParticulateDensity)
{ 
this->aveParticulateDensity = aveParticulateDensity;

}

void locationdata::set_avePlasmaDensity(float avePlasmaDensity)
{
this->avePlasmaDensity = avePlasmaDensity;
}


string locationdata::get_sunType()
{ 
return this->sunType;
}

int locationdata::get_noOfEarthLikePlanets()
{
return this->noOfEarthLikePlanets;
}

int locationdata::get_noOfEarthLikeMoons()
{
return this->noOfEarthLikeMoons;
}

float locationdata::get_aveParticulateDensity()
{
return this->aveParticulateDensity;
}

float locationdata::get_avePlasmaDensity()
{
return this->avePlasmaDensity;

}

float locationdata::computeCivIndex()
{
string temp = this->get_sunType();
int sunTypePercent;
float CivIndex ;

if ( temp == "Type O")
{
sunTypePercent = 30;
}
else if ( temp == "Type B")
{
sunTypePercent = 45;

}
else if ( temp == "Type A")
{ 
sunTypePercent = 60; 

 }
else if ( temp == "Type F")
{ 
sunTypePercent = 75;
}
else if ( temp =="Type G")
{
 sunTypePercent = 90;
}
else if ( temp =="Type K")
{
 sunTypePercent = 80;
}
else if ( temp =="Type M")
{
 sunTypePercent = 70; 
}




           CivIndex=1.5;

          return CivIndex;
}
```

Sub class PointTwoD.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "locationdata.h"

using namespace std;

class PointTwoD:public locationdata
{
  public:
  PointTwoD();

  private:
  int x;
  int y;
  float civIndex;




};
```

Sub class PointTwoD.cpp

```
   #include "PointTwoD.h"

 PointTwoD::PointTwoD()
{
  this ->x = 0;
  this->y = 0;

   this->set_sunType("");
   this->set_noOfEarthLikePlanets(0);
   this->set_noOfEarthLikeMoons(0);
   this->set_aveParticulateDensity(0);
   this->set_avePlasmaDensity(0);

}
```

main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PointTwoD.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int choice;
PointTwoD test; //undefined reference
test.set_noOfEarthLikeMoons(10); // undefined reference
cout<<test.get_noOfEarthLikeMoons() //undefined reference
}
```

Comment: I think you are not including all the files when you compile. How are you compiling your project?

Comment: @jxh i am compiling this using quincy 2005 , i just put all the files in the same folder

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea how to help you with that. You will have to read the documentation on how to add multiple source files to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile a project that involves multiple source files (ie., `.cc` or `.cpp` files), you have to make sure each file is involved when you want to create the executable. How that is accomplished depends on your compiler, but with `g++`, I did this, and it compiled fine (after adding a missing `;` to the last `cout` statement in your `main()`):

```
g++ main.cpp locationdata.cpp PointTwoD.cpp
```